# Why this code is not running as per expectation on AARCH64

Tags: c, timer, linux-device-driver, arm64

Sorry for putting up so many questions on this topic but still not sure why I am not getting expected result.

Idea is to get the timestamps from CPU's cyclic counter register on AARCH64.

I am expecting this module to return nanoseconds since the system boot and then using following tool convert it to current timestamps

http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-5.5&timestamp=41522432&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++

```
#define MODULE
#define LINUX
#define __KERNEL__

#include <linux/module.h>  /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */


#define read_cntv_frq(cntv_frq)   \
do {    \
 __asm__ __volatile("mrs %0,   cntfrq_el0; isb; " \
 : "=r" (cntv_frq)); \
} while (0);

#define read_cntv_vct(cntv_vct)   \
do {    \
 __asm__ __volatile("isb; mrs %0, cntvct_el0; isb ;" \
: "=r" (cntv_vct)); \ 
} while (0);


int init_module(void)  
{

  #define NANO_PER_SEC 1000000000  

  u64 cntv_vct ;
  u32 cntv_frq ;

  read_cntv_frq(cntv_frq);
  read_cntv_vct(cntv_vct);

  cntv_vct = ((__uint128_t)cntv_vct * NANO_PER_SEC) ;

  cntv_vct = do_div(cntv_vct, cntv_frq);

  printk(KERN_DEBUG "***cnt_vct***=0x%08llx\n",
                 cntv_vct);

  // A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
   printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

But I am seeing a timestamps of 1970's, Can some one please look into it.

Thanks.

Comment: In what way would you expect "number of nanoseconds since system boot" and "number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00" to be equivalent?

Comment: Ok, Are you saying I need to make sure that I would get number of nanoseconds since epoch time not since system boot?

Comment: The counter you're reading starts at 0 from powerup and ticks monotonically upwards. The frequency lets you translate "number of ticks since powerup" into "number of time units since powerup"; you clearly can't get an _absolute_ timestamp (i.e. relative to wall-clock time) from that without some external point of reference, so I'm not really sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: Thanks @Notlikethat, your comments helped me getting better picture, wanted to ask you few more doubts 1) Where these counters are initialized to zero, is it in Bootloader ? 2).  if I lunch a guest machine on top this host wouldn't I see progressive values of this counter on guest side as guest and host reads same CNTVCT counters?

Comment: Also, when load this module into guest , I always see this counter value zero, why guest don't see the Updated CNTVCT counters?